# Is it possible to reference same ascx user control within the same ascx control

Tags: asp.net, controls

Is it possible to use/reference same ascx user control within the same ascx control?
Primarily we want a popup within a popup within a popup - n level based on a condition. The popup is the user control.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is possible when loading/adding the control programmatically, e.g:

```
this.Controls.Add(LoadControl("~/mycontrol.ascx"));
```

But if you do this unconditionally, then you'll get an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can not :  `Circular file references are not allowed.`

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebUserControl1" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="test" TagName="test" Src="~/WebUserControl1.ascx"%>
```

This code is not possible